# Rails Delete link is generating a Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a shopping cart and each product has a delete link that generates the following message when clicked:

> Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/order_items/8"

The only change between the errors generated by each link is the order_item id.

The code is the following:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", order_item, { data: { confirm: "Are you sure you wish to delete the product '#{order_item.product.name}' from your cart?" }, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-danger" } %>
```

This is the generated link:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure you wish to delete the product 'Name' from your cart?" class="btn btn-danger" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/order_items/8">Delete</a>
```

This is the relevant data in routes file:

```
resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

When clicked, the alert pops up but the log shows this:

> DELETE http://localhost:3000/order_items/11 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

What am I missing for the code to work.

Comment: Does it really redirect or did you forget to import jquery-ujs (which sends the DELETE http verb)

Comment: It is being called from application.js as follows `//= require jquery_ujs` and the gem `jquery-rails` is called on the Gemfile. I added the generated HTML in case something is wrong with it.

Comment: Please add your logs too.

Comment: @RaVeN you were, right I was not including the application javascript in my layout now the javascript confirmation appears but the log shows this: " DELETE http://localhost:3000/order_items/8 422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this behavior by adding the following line to my layout's head:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative may be to trade out `[:delete, order_item]` for `order_item`.

As in:

`<%= link_to "Delete", [:delete, order_item], { data: { confirm: "Are you sure you wish to delete the product '#{order_item.product.name}' from your cart?" }, remote: true, class: "btn btn-danger" } %>`

Comment: This results in a No Method Error `undefined method delete_order_item_path' for #<#<Class:0x0055af888929b0>:0x0055af8a15c680>`